# How to obtain xyz-axes of same length?

Tags: plotting, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Controlling the 2D $x–y$ aspect ratio of a 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9171/controlling-the-2d-xy-aspect-ratio-of-a-3d-plot)

I am plotting 1000 points in a 3-dimensional cartesian coordinate system, the plotting range for the x, y, z axes is set to {-1,1} respectively.

Mathematica code:

```
points1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {500, 3}];
points2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {500, 3}];

sphere = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}];
plot1 = ListPointPlot3D[points1, PlotStyle -> Green];
plot2 = ListPointPlot3D[points2, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[{plot1, plot2, sphere}, Axes -> False,
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Why does Mathematica plots axes of different lengths? Since I have given the same plotting range, I would expect and want to see a cube. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use `BoxRatios -> Automatic`.

Comment: Wonderful! It works.