# AspectRatio in Plot3D

Tags: graphics3d

How to achieve that all three axes are depicted with the same scale in `Plot3D`?

No matter what value I set for `AspectRatio` (`1`, `Automatic`...) - the sphere always look as ellipsoid and the look of it even changes with every manual rotation by mouse.

```
Plot3D[{Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling the 2D $x–y$ aspect ratio of a 3D plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9171/controlling-the-2d-x-y-aspect-ratio-of-a-3d-plot)

Comment: It is similar question, but concentrates on `Graphics3D` and `ListPlot3D` which do not behave in all circumstances same as `Plot3D`. For example if you plot single sphere in `Graphics3D` without any `AspectRatio` or `BoxRatios` it is always depicted as sphere not ellipsoid, on the other hand you see from my code that sphere in `Plot3D` is depicted as ellipsoid. But both question can be solved with setting `BoxRatios`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `BoxRatios -> Automatic`

```
   n = 2;
    Plot3D[{Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n},
     BoxRatios -> Automatic,
     Axes -> True,
     Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

```
n = 2;
Plot3D[{Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], -Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n},
 BoxRatios -> Automatic,
 ViewPoint -> Right,
 PlotPoints -> 40,
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, I overlooked this option since there are so many.